# Is it possible to navigate through nodes on Node-RED using only the keyboard?

Tags: node-red

I've recently found out how to use the function and template nodes with the `vim` mode on `Node-RED`. It's nice as I don't rely too much on the mouse while I'm editing code inside a specific node... However, even though I can open nodes pressing `Enter` and confirm their edition with `Ctrl+Enter`, I'm not capable of navigating through the grid of nodes with the keyboard.

The arrow keys work only to move them around and I haven't found anything related to that on the "keyboard shortcuts" configuration. Am I missing something? Is it possible to navigate through nodes without using the mouse on `Node-RED`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change the current selection via just the keyboard.

It would be a useful feature to have, we can add an item to the backlog for it.

Comment: I see... It'd be nice if this feature could be added in a future version :). Also, I've realized that when we press enter on the template or function nodes to open it, the pointer is not ready for typing new code (that means I need to press Tab six times to get there)... With the idea of navigating through nodes with the keyboard I think that opening these two nodes in a way that they are ready for typing code would be nice too